# Select a value after an input select is populated dynamically with change event

Tags: jquery, dom

I have two inputs select, the second one populates when one value is selected at the first input select, it works.

I'm selecting a value dinamically and the second select is populating, but the problem comes when I want to select the option from the second input select. I can't do it.

The ajax is executing in other file so I can't modify the ajax, the only I want is to select the option dinamically when the value appear at the DOM.

```
 <script>
    jQuery($).ready(function(){
       //here I'm selecting a option from land and region is populating properly
       jQuery("#land option[value={VALUE1}]").attr("selected","selected").change();

       //when I try to select the region dinamically it doesn't work
       jQuery("#region option[value={VALUE2}]").attr("selected","selected").change();
     });
 </script>
```

I want to select a value from the second input.

I seems that the value isn't there,

Maybe using event handler, could solve it.
how can solve this porblem?

Comment: You can't set attributes or trigger events on elements that doesn't exist yet, you have to call the bottom line inside whatever function that inserts the elements.

Comment: Lets see that AJAX function!

Comment: I want execute it on page load

Comment: @sebasparola -- You can't do that man, the element's values don't exist yet. You're going to have to edit the AJAX call, more specifically, the `success` method to set this once it completes.

Comment: the ajax is not the problem because if I select a option manually, works fine. Instead do it manually, I want to select options dinamically.

Comment: there are some way to execute the first line, and then execute the second one when the DOM is ready???

Comment: It doesn't matter if the DOM is ready, the elements ***are not there*** until after you have inserted them, and you ***can not select something that isn't there*** !

Comment: I'm not saying the AJAX is the "problem", I'm saying it needs to be edited, or else this WON'T work (programatically).

Comment: But in some moment those elements appear so, there are some way to execute the second line after it appear??

Comment: Yes, and that would be after whenever you insert them, probably inside the success handler of an ajax function or the change event handler for the first select etc.

Comment: So how can I use the event handler, can you help me?

Comment: @adeneo could you help me? how can I use the change event handler?

Comment: @tymeJV do you know some way I can use the event handler?

Comment: The `change` handler wouldn't be an option I dont think since you have to wait for the AJAX to finish, that's where the `success` method comes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sample AJAX function that is based off of the first select, you select the make of a car, it makes a call to a database and returns all the options of the second option

```
$("#make").change(function(){
    $("#model").attr("disabled", false);
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://website.com/vehicle/getmodel.php",
        data: {make: $(make).val()},
        type: "post",
        success: function(msg){
        $("#model").html(msg);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Okay, let me know if you need help. and mark it as answered to close the question